# Are deflection of compass and speed of electron relative to each other?

Tags: electromagnetism

If one holds an electron in one hand and a compass in the other hand, and the starts running at the speed of light holding those, then will there be any deflection of the compass ?

Comment: Why do you expect there to be a change? The charge doesn't generate any magnetic field from the viewpoint of the compass.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to the compass, the electron is at rest. An electron at rest cannot produce a magnetic field. So the compass will not show any deflection.